# error executable compile with static library

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, static-linking

i have some static library in this directory >> /home/mycomputer/src/lib  .
name liba.a libb.a libc.a libd.a
i have the code on /home/sugonsky/src
name code.cpp

i have been try compile it on g++
the command is

```
g++ code.cpp -o myExecutable -L/home/mycomputer/src/lib/liba.a -L/home/mycomputer/src/lib/libb.a -L/home/mycomputer/src/lib/libc.a -L/home/mycomputer/src/lib/libd.a
```

what i am trying to say is that why i always get

```
/tmp/ccJLJTpi.o: In function `cv::Mat::operator()(cv::Rect_<int> const&) const':
faceDetection.cpp:(.text._ZNK2cv3MatclERKNS_5Rect_IiEE[_ZNK2cv3MatclERKNS_5Rect_IiEE]+0x27): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Rect_<int> const&)'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

is there any wrong step on my compilation scheme?

Answer (score 1):

`-L/path/to/library/` and `-lName` as g++ options worked for me. Do not specify the library name in the `path/to/library`.

Comment: i doing like you said but i got this >> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -la.a